# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str' using Pyner for Name entity recognition

Tags: string, python-3.x, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to pass an email string to Pyner to pull out all the entities into a dictionary. I can verify my setup works with this returning two PERSON entities

```
import ner
tagger = ner.SocketNER(port=9191, output_format='slashTags')
t = "My daughter Sophia goes to the university of California. James also goes there"
print(type(t))
test = tagger.get_entities(t)
person_ents = test['PERSON']
for i in person_ents:
    print(i)
```

This outputs as expected

```
Sophia
James
```

The only difference is here that I have email text here instead I can verify it's a string

```
print(type(firstEmail))

test = tagger.get_entities(firstEmail)
person_ents = test['PERSON']
print (type(person_ents))
for i in person_ents:
    print(i)
```

This returns the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-ff847452c8df> in <module>()
      3 
      4 
----> 5 test = tagger.get_entities(firstEmail)
      6 person_ents = test['PERSON']
      7 print (type(person_ents))

~/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ner-0.1-py3.6.egg/ner/client.py in get_entities(self, text)
     90         else: #inlineXML
     91             entities = self.__inlineXML_parse_entities(tagged_text)
---> 92         return self.__collapse_to_dict(entities)
     93 
     94     def json_entities(self, text):

~/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ner-0.1-py3.6.egg/ner/client.py in __collapse_to_dict(self, pairs)
     71         """
     72         return dict((first, list(map(itemgetter(1), second))) for (first, second)
---> 73             in groupby(sorted(pairs, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0)))
     74 
     75     def get_entities(self, text):

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Any idea how what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that NER is setup so that when the output is set to SlashTags it output a dictionary format. However the text is parsed with slash characters where a named entity occurs and this character is then used to separate dictionary entity before the dictionary is generated. As a result if any slashes occur in your text data you need to parse this out.

Something like

```
#text is your string
text = text.replace('/', '-')
```

This shouldn't be an issue in NLP terms as dates should still be picked out with this format. But if some key part of your analysis requires this tag to be there this solution might not be suitable. I can't verify if this issue exists in the java implementation but it's possible